# How to change the axis dimension from pixel to length in matplotlib? is there any code in general?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Since the complete simulation is to big to post it right here only the code to plot the spectrum is given (I think this is enough)

```
d = i.sum(axis=2)
pylab.figure(figsize=(15,15))
pylab = imshow(d)
plt.axis('tight')
pylab.show()
```

This spectrum is given in pixel. But I would like to have this in the units of length. I will hope you may give me some advices.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want axis ticks to show your custom dimensions instead of the number of pixels in `d`? If yes, use the `extent` keyword of `imshow`:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = numpy.random.normal(size=(20, 40))

fig = plt.figure()
s = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
s.imshow(d, extent=(0, 1, 0, 0.5), interpolation='none')
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('tt.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess a bit at what your problem is, so let's start by stating my interpretation/ You have some 2D data `d` that you plot using `imshow` and the units on the `x` and `y` axes are in the number of pixels. For example in the following we see the `x` axis labelled from 0 -> 10 for the number of data points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate a fake d
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
d = np.sin(X**2 + Y**2)

plt.imshow(d)
```

[image]

If this correctly describes your issue, then the solution is to avoid using `imshow`, which is designed to plot images. Firstly this will help as `imshow` attemps to interpolate to give a smoother image (which may hide features in the spectrum) and second because it is an image, there is no meaningful `x` and `y` data so it doesn't plot it.

The best alternative would be to use `plt.pcolormesh` which generate a psuedocolor plot of a 2D array and takes as arguments `X` and `Y`, which are both 2D arrays of points to which the values of `d` correspond.

For example:

```
# Generate a fake d
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
d = np.sin(X**2 + Y**2)

plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, d)
```

[image]

Now the `x` and `y` values correspond to the values of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Why avoid `imshow`? Just use the `extent` keyword argument.

Comment: I prefer this method it is more transparent and avoid interpolation

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Both cases worked. Best,Victor.